# invalid template argument for 'N', expected compile-time constant expression

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a high precision floating point library (for educational purpose) and the constructors are shown below.

The idea is to have a generic constructor (the first one) and then 2 specialized constructors for std::string and std::bitset.

The problem is that I keep getting: "error C2975: 'Float' : invalid template argument for 'N', expected compile-time constant expression" for both specialized constructors.

Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Thanks in advance!

```
template<typename T>
Float(T n) {
    type_wrapper<T> data;
    data.in = n;
    bits = std::bitset<N>(data.out);
    _overflow = false;
}

template<>
Float< const std::bitset<N> >(const std::bitset<N> bits) {
    this->bits = bits;
    _overflow = false;
}

template<>
Float< const std::string& >(const std::string& s) {
    int n = std::min(N, s.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bits[n-i-1] = (s.at(i) == '1' ? 1 : 0);
    }
    _overflow = false;
}
```

EDIT: I should probably add that I'm actually constructing a Float object with a constant size like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Float<64> number("01011001100010001110010101100111");   //1502143847
    std::cout << number << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Also the templated argument 'N' is from the class definition like so:

```
template<size_t N>
class Float
{
private:
    ...
public:
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specialize your constructor, use overloading.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
template<std::size_t N>
class Float
{
private:

public:
  template<typename T>
  Float(const T& n) {
  }

  Float(const std::bitset<N>& bits) {
  }

  Float(const std::string& s) {
  }
};

int main()
{
    Float<64> number("01011001100010001110010101100111");   //1502143847

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The original error is probably because you don't fully qualify your constructs when defining them. This should be:

```
template<std::size_t N>
template<>
Float<N>::Float<const std::string&>(const std::string&) {}
```

Comment: Originally I did overload the constructors, but the problem is that the generic constructor is called every time instead of the more specific constructors.
The constructors are also fully qualified since the 'N' template parameter is defined at the top of the class definition.

Comment: @MathiasVorreiterPedersen That can't be right. Can you show the code that caused this? Although in the case of the `string` overload and calling with a string literal this is the expected behavior. The generated constructor (from the template instantiation) `Float(char*)` is higher ranked than the one requiring the conversion to `string`. In general, this shouldn't be true.

Comment: You were right. When I explicitly constructed a std::string object from the string literal the correct constructor was applied. So I guess all works well if I just create another constructor for a char* argument. Thank you!